# URLDownloadToFile cannot update progress properly?

Tags: file, delphi, download

I try to use `URLDownloadToFile` to download a large file in Delphi XE3. I want it to show the download progress.

Below is my code

```pascal
unit MainFrm;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, WUpdate, Vcl.StdCtrls, IdBaseComponent,
  IdComponent, IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, IdHTTP, UrlMon, ActiveX,
  Vcl.ComCtrls;

const
     S_ABORT = HRESULT($80004004);

type
     TDownLoadMonitor = class( TInterfacedObject, IBindStatusCallback)
     private
      FProgressBar: TProgressBar;
         FShouldAbort: Boolean;
     protected
        function OnStartBinding( dwReserved: DWORD; pib: IBinding ): HResult; stdcall;
        function GetPriority( out nPriority ): HResult; stdcall;
        function OnLowResource( reserved: DWORD ): HResult; stdcall;
        function OnProgress( ulProgress, ulProgressMax, ulStatusCode: ULONG;
             szStatusText: LPCWSTR): HResult; stdcall;
        function OnStopBinding( hresult: HResult; szError: LPCWSTR ): HResult; stdcall;
        function GetBindInfo( out grfBINDF: DWORD; var bindinfo: TBindInfo ): HResult; stdcall;
        function OnDataAvailable( grfBSCF: DWORD; dwSize: DWORD; formatetc: PFormatEtc;
             stgmed: PStgMedium ): HResult; stdcall;
        function OnObjectAvailable( const iid: TGUID; punk: IUnknown ): HResult; stdcall;
     public
         constructor Create(ProgressBar: TProgressBar);
         property ShouldAbort: Boolean read FShouldAbort write FShouldAbort;
    end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    ProgressBar1: TProgressBar;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);private
    FMonitor: TDownloadMonitor;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

Uses ShellAPI, System.IniFiles;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  URLDownloadToFile(nil, 'https://www.datanumen.com/dwg-recovery/ddwgr.exe', PChar('E:\Temp\ddwgr.exe'), 0, FMonitor as IBindStatusCallback);

end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FMonitor := TDownloadMonitor.Create(ProgressBar1);
end;

constructor TDownLoadMonitor.Create(ProgressBar: TProgressBar);
begin
     inherited Create;
     FProgressBar := ProgressBar;
     FShouldAbort:=False;
end;

function TDownLoadMonitor.GetBindInfo( out grfBINDF: DWORD; var bindinfo: TBindInfo ): HResult;
begin
     result := S_OK;
end;

function TDownLoadMonitor.GetPriority( out nPriority ): HResult;
begin
     Result := S_OK;
end;

function TDownLoadMonitor.OnDataAvailable( grfBSCF, dwSize: DWORD; formatetc: PFormatEtc; stgmed: PStgMedium ): HResult;
begin
     Result := S_OK;
end;

function TDownLoadMonitor.OnLowResource( reserved: DWORD ): HResult;
begin
     Result := S_OK;
end;

function TDownLoadMonitor.OnObjectAvailable( const iid: TGUID; punk: IInterface ): HResult;
begin
     Result := S_OK;
end;

function TDownLoadMonitor.OnProgress( ulProgress, ulProgressMax, ulStatusCode: ULONG; szStatusText: LPCWSTR ): HResult;
begin
    if Assigned(FProgressBar) then
    begin
      if ulStatusCode = BINDSTATUS_BEGINDOWNLOADDATA then
      begin
        FProgressBar.Min := 0;
        FProgressBar.Max := ulProgressMax;
      end
      else if ulStatusCode = BINDSTATUS_DOWNLOADINGDATA then
        FProgressBar.Position := ulProgress;
    end;

    if FShouldAbort then
         Result := E_ABORT
    else
         Result := S_OK;
end;

function TDownLoadMonitor.OnStartBinding( dwReserved: DWORD; pib: IBinding ): HResult;
begin
     Result := S_OK;
end;

function TDownLoadMonitor.OnStopBinding( hresult: HResult; szError: LPCWSTR ): HResult;
begin
     Result := S_OK;
end;

end.
```

The problem is that the progress bar is displayed incorrectly. I try to debug `TDownLoadMonitor.OnProgress` and find `ulProgress` is always the same value as `ulProgressMax`, they change from small values, such as 0,0 to 95374,95374 then 347227,347227 and increase gradually, but always the same value, so the progress bar is always about 100%.

Why does it not show the actual download progress properly?

Comment: Not related to your issue, but your `FMonitor` member should be declared as `IBindStatusCallback`, not `TDownloadMonitor`. You are not managing the object’s reference count properly.

Comment: The third comment to the duplicate question explains why the progress indication may fail.